# How to get same attribute of multiple objects in a JSON file using Java?

Tags: java, json, jsonparser, json-simple

I have a JSON file that has stock data of different portfolios.

```java
[
    {
        "name": "octoberportfolio", 
        "pathame": "C:\\Users\\Documents\\octoberportfolio.xlsx", 
        "stocks" :
             {
                "SWN": ["Southwestern Energy", 34, 23],
                "TSLA": ["Tesla", 4, 2100],
                "HPE": ["Hewlett Packard Enterprise", 9, 400]
            }
    },

    {
        "name": "jasonportfolio", 
        "pathame": "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Java\\jasonportfolio.xlsx", 
        "stocks" :
             {
                "AAPL": ["Apple", 34, 23],
                "MSFT": ["Microsoft", 4, 2100],
                "BAB": ["Alibaba", 9, 400]
            }

    }
]
```

I'd like to add the key values for "name" to an ArrayList `["octoberportfolio", "jasonportfolio"]`. How would I do this? The only solution I've seen online is if there is only one object in the file.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like the `stocks` would be a Map

Comment: Further, it looks like the stock object, eg `["Apple", 34, 23]` should not be an array of untyped objects, ie `Object[]`, but should be an object, eg `{"name":"Apple", "num1" : 34, "num2" : 23}`

Comment: @Bohemian The reason I wrote it like that is because I needed to have multiple attributes for multiple stocks, and not just one stock

Comment: @WilhelmoGutred what I mean is `"stocks": { "APPL": {"name":"Apple", "num1" : 34, "num2" : 23}, "MSFT": {"name":"Microsoft", "num1" : 4, "num2" : 2100} }`

Comment: @Bohemian oh ok I understand now, I was just wondering how you would get the values for the "name" key for both portfolios

Comment: Use jackson's ObjectMapper and deserialize into a class that includes a field `Map<String, Object[]> stocks;` and go from there.